# How to make two boxplots in the same plot?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

For university, I am tasked to create two whisker-boxplots side-by-side in the same plot. *(And then make critical comments and observations about them)*

The `sway` data frame this exercise is based on, can be obtained by the following R commands:

```
sway <-
  structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                 .Label = c("Elderly", "Young"), class = "factor"),
                 FBSway = c(19L, 30L, 20L, 19L, 29L, 25L, 21L, 24L, 50L, 25L, 21L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 22L, 17L), 
                 SideSway = c(14L, 41L, 18L, 11L, 16L, 24L, 18L, 21L, 37L, 17L, 10L, 16L, 22L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 18L)),
            .Names = c("Age", "FBSway", "SideSway"),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

The idea is that we create a boxplot of `sway$FBsway` for both the `Young` as the `Elderly` age groups, in the same plot.

I know about the `par(mfrows=c(1,2))` function, but this creates two loose plots, side-by-side.

How do I transform the `sway` data frame into a format that `boxplot()` can use to create the desired boxplots in a single plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
plot(as.numeric(sway$FBSway) ~as.factor(sway$Age))
```

Comment: Wow! That does exactly what I want! Could you elaborate on why the `as.numeric` and `as.factor` casts are necessary here, for this to work?

Comment: Or was the problem here that I blindly stared at `boxplot()` whereas `plot()` 'just makes' a boxplot for you, given the correct input?

Comment: Actually they might not be so necessary. I just did so to keep things unambiguous .  And to further remove any ambiguity, you can substitute `plot` with `boxplot`

Comment: It's the formula sign, ~ that made it  the generic plot function call boxplot. It calls plot.formula And here's quoting from the documentation for plot.formula : `If y is an object (i.e., has a class attribute) then plot.formula looks for a plot method for that class first. Otherwise, the class of x will determine the type of the plot. For factors this will be a parallel boxplot, and argument horizontal = TRUE can be specified`

Comment: I see! I tried the `~`-syntax before, but having `sway$Age` as the first operand. This threw an error.

Comment: I use the mnemonic 'y axis depends on x axis' to remember  `y~x`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
sway <- melt(sway)

ggplot(sway, aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~Age)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(sway, aes(Age, value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]